# Trouble connecting to Oracle database with sqlplus and OS authentication

Tags: oracle, powershell

I am a read-only user to an oracle database, and the DBA gave me two accounts, one with a specific user name and password, and another with OS authentication. The OS authentication is supposed to let me connect by authenticating with my active directory user account that I use to login to my laptop, where I am then running sqlplus.

I can connect and start querying just fine with this command, which shows it is picking up my tnsnames file:

```
sqlplus username/password@database
```

However, the version to connect with OS authentication doesn't work:

```
sqlplus /@database

ERROR: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

**Am I doing something obviously wrong?** I checked in powershell that my user and domain name are the user and domain name that was set up for OS authentication for this database.

I did another test, this time using powershell to do the connection and again with my AD login that should work:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
    
#This connection string works for the normal authenticated account
$connectionString = "User Id=$username;Password=$password;Data Source=$datasource"
    
#But this one gives me ORA-01017 invalid username/password
$connectionString = "User Id=/;Data Source=$datasource"
    
$connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$connection.open()
```

I also made sure that SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS) is in the sqlnet.ora file

Any thoughts?

Comment: In your connection string, make sure you're appending `Integrated Security=yes` as part of your connection string

Comment: Here is a link to [Oracle Base explaining OS-Authentication](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/os-authentication). You can see that your dbuser should be created this way "CREATE USER "OPS$ORACLE-BASE.COM\TIM_HALL" IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY;" All in all I think this is a problem your dbadmin should try to solve. Are there other OsAuthenticated user in this database that already can login? "sqlplus /@database" is ok if 'database' points to the right database.

Comment: Is this really OS authentication? To use that kind of login, usually Kerberos authentication is configured. To have `sqlplus /@database` working with Kerberos authentication, you need to set some extra parameters in the client `sqlnet.ora` (enable Kerberos authentication, enable the use of Windows credential cache), which the DBA should be able to provide. First clarify that.

Comment: I tried adding Integrated Security=yes  to my connection string but it isn't a valid parameter for my type of connection, thank you though. Also, I don't have a lot of insight to the DBA side of the configuration. The DBA says it is good to go so I figured the problem was on my side with how I'm connecting. And good point on Kerberos, I don't know specifically other than that it is set up for "external users", I will ask about Kerberos specifically.

Answer (score 1):

For anything looking for an answer: I was connecting the correct way. On the backend, remote_os_authent was set to false, which would not allow this kind of authentication.

Comment: `remote_os_authent=true`. So I guess cybersecurity and audits are of no concern at all at your organization.

Comment: I agree: setting remote_os_authent=true is one of the worst possible security holes your system could have... i hope this is just for training purposes and not for anything real.